# 2013 Stand Alone

Tags: standalone

I have access to a PC with VM Player and would like to install a stand alone version of SharePoint 2013. Do you know a source where I could get this (have been advised non hyper-v)> Thanks

Comment: Whate you are searching for is called "Sharepoint 2013 On-Premise Installation" A quick google search should help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

he good news for all the developer SharePoint 2013 VM now available for download.Thanks for the `http://www.pilothouseconsulting.com` team to provide the Virtual Image. Just Click the below link to download the SharePoint 2013 VM (Fill the simple form you will revived the download details by email).

[image]

http://sharepointfordeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-vm-vmware-vmx-player-to.html